# XSLT issue simple

Tags: xml, xslt

Could someone help with this issue ? :

this my xml file called ce.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ce.xslt"?>
<TABLE>
   <CE>
      <Variable> STUDYID </Variable>
      <Label> Study Identifier </Label>
      <length> 200 </length>
      <Type> Char </Type>
   </CE>
   <CE>
      <Variable> DOMAIN </Variable>
      <Label> Domain Abbreviation </Label>
      <length> 200 </length>
      <Type> Char </Type>
   </CE>
 <TABLE>
```

I would to render in html only the values of the variable "Variable",which are domain and studyid. So I used the following xslt transformation :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">


<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Get all Variables</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <xsl:for-each select="/TABLE/CE"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="Variable"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't understand, it should work as it is quite a basic query. Note that it failed on all browsers.

Thanks in advance

saskap

Comment: @CAFEBABE Please don't edit OP code.

Comment: Wasn't expecting this to be the error. Looked more like laziness to me. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your input is not well-formed XML: the final `<TABLE>` needs to be
   `</TABLE>`.
2. Instead of :

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="/TABLE/CE"/>
   ```

   you need:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="/TABLE/CE">
   ```